# How to create an iOS signing key?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using PhoneGap Build to build my app. I am not sure how do i create a iOS Signing key since i am using a windows machine.

I was able to create a key for Android using following command .

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

However i am not sure how do i create one for iOS ? Can someone link me with a tutorial on how to create a key on windows machine ?

```
You must provide a signing key, first. Find out how to fix this.
```

Comment: Have you signed up for an [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) account? You can read how to sign for iOS in the [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/signing_signing-ios.md.html#iOS%20Signing).

Comment: @AndrewLively Yes indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, [this blog post](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows/) offers all necessary steps. Here is a summery:

1. Get the OpenSSL
2. Generate a private Key `openssl genrsa -des3 -out ios.key 2048`
3. Generate a Certificate Signing Request or CSR file

   openssl req -new -key ios.key -out ios.csr -subj "/emailAddress=MY-EMAIL-ADDRESS, CN=COMPANY-NAME, C=COUNTRY-CODE"
4. On [Apple Developer iOS Provisioning Portal](http://Apple%20Developer%20iOS%20Provisioning%20Portal), generate an iOS Development Certificate, using the ios.csr file you've just generated.
5. Convert Certification into a PEM file: `openssl x509 -in ios_development.cer -inform DER -out ios_development.pem -outform PEM`
6. Generate P12 file: `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ios.key -in ios_development.pem -out ios_development.p12`
7. The last file you need to generate is the provisioning profile, using the Apple Provisioning Portal.

I strongly suggest you to follow the steps on the [original post](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows/).

Answer (score -2):

you can't create a signing key through a window system you must to create an apple account with any MAC book and than you can create the certificate for developer and distribution
developer certificate is used for device testing 
else
distribution is used for any testing and publish an app on IOS